# PHPUnit Assert One of two possible outcomes

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I am writing unit tests to validate the functionality of two libraries is the same. Essentially, testing an interface.

However, in some tests related to error handling. The error level is different and it has to be different because for example, one generates E_WARNING and the other can only generate E_USER_WARNING.

So the question is. Is there an assert in PHP unit which can say, the error must be one of two possible results? Something like:

```
assertIsIn(array(E_WARNING, E_USER_WARNING), $generatedError);
```

I know I could probably work around it by swapping the expected and actual answers over in assertContains() or possibly some pre-assert manipulation of results. However is there a cleaner approach?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably you can implement with the [assertContains](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html#appendixes.assertions.assertContains) method (Asserts that a haystack contains a needle). As Example:

```
public function testAssertIsIn()
{
    $errorLevel = array(E_WARNING, E_USER_WARNING);

    $generatedError = E_WARNING;
    $this->assertContains($generatedError, $errorLevel);

    $generatedError = E_USER_WARNING;
    $this->assertContains($generatedError, $errorLevel);
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Good answer, I hand't spotted that assetContains syntax is needle/haystack instead of expected/actual in the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->logicalOr( $this->identicalTo( E_WARNING ), $this->identicalTo( E_USER_WARNING ) );
```

If you want cleaner code, you can turn it into a custom assertion:

```
public static function assertOneOf( array $expected, $actual, $message = '' ) {
    $constraints = [];
    foreach ( $expected as $expectedValue ) {
        $constrains[] = new PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_IsIdentical( $expectedValue );
    }
    $constraint = new PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_Or;
    $constraint->setConstraints( $constraints );
    self::assertThat( $actual, $constraints, $message );
}
```

Comment: `PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_IsIdentical` is unknown class. At least in phpunit 7.5. I'll go with `assertContains()` but this approach would be nicer.

Comment: It's [PHPUnit\Framework\Constraint\IsIdentical](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/src/Framework/Constraint/IsIdentical.php) now. PHPUnit has abandoned the old PEAR style underscore class names a long time ago.